# Get ID and name of each customer and the total sum (sum of quantity of products purchased)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with this JOIN + SUM query

What I have are these following tables (Client, orders, product)

| client_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Frank |
| 2 | Emile |
| 3 | Rose |
| 4 | Laura |
| 5 | Samuel |

| order_number | client_id | product_id | units_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 18 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 19 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 12 |

| product_id | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rice | 26.10 |
| 2 | Coffee | 12.50 |
| 4 | Sugar | 13 |
| 5 | Beans | 5.40 |
| 3 | Milk | 30.00 |

What I'm trying to do is generate a query that shows the ID and name of each customer and the total sum (sum of quantity of products purchased).

So far, my logic without breaking it is this:

```
Select 
c.client_id, c.first_name
from client c
INNER JOIN orders o on o.client_id = c.client_id
```

I want to add the SUM part to it but whenever I try it, the new query line doesn't work

Comment: can you add a table of the expected result?

Comment: total products purchased is the grand total regardless of the product_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the sum of quantity of products:

```
SELECT c.client_id, c.first_name, SUM(o.units_sold)
FROM
    client c
    INNER JOIN orders o ON o.client_id = c.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id, c.first_name;
```

But if you also want to see the price:

```
SELECT c.client_id, c.first_name, SUM(o.units_sold), 
SUM(o.units_sold*p.price)
FROM
    client c
    INNER JOIN orders o ON o.client_id = c.client_id
    INNER JOIN products p ON o.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY c.client_id, c.first_name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't so wrong after all, I thought the SUM came after the FROM and not before. I just have a question: What does the GROUP BY do in this query? And, Can the query work without it?